# WKHTMLTOPDF and Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, wkhtmltopdf

Is it possible to use coldfusion URL variables with WKHTMLTOPDF plugin? I am trying it as follows but only receiving a blank PDF. I'm assuming it's failing because of the URL variables.

```
 <cfexecute name="C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe" 
    arguments="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\serviceticket\reports\dropoff_receipt.cfm?ticket_id=#url.ticketID#&signature_id=#check_signature.id# C:\google.pdf"
    timeout="10" />
```

**Update 1:**

Changed the source to a URL, same error though.

```
    <cfexecute name="C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe" 
    arguments="'../../serviceticket/reports/dropoff_receipt.cfm?ticket_id=#url.ticketID#&signature_id=#check_signature.id# C:\google.pdf"
    timeout="10" />
```

**Update 2:**

After adding the full URL, here is a screenshot of the PDF that is now made. It's obviously not blank but the path of the URL in the error message is way different than the URL I am specifying.??

[image]
-Brian

Comment: Couple things 1) Before plugging it into cfexecute, did you verify it works via the command line? (I am guessing not). 2) Always use `errorVariable` or `errorFile`, otherwise you won't be able to see any errors that may occur 3) Any URL variables will be evaluated and converted into strings before they ever reach the program. As long as the resulting value is a valid argument it should work fine 4) Finally, in order for the CFML code in that file to be evaluated, you must call it as a URL, *not* a local file.

Comment: Doesn't ColdFusion have a built in PDF generator? `<cfpdf>`

Comment: You're right, I didn't test it originally. Tested it now via CLI and it is definitely working. How do I specify the errorVariable or errorFile? I don't see that in the documentation. Also, changed the source to a URL, same error though. I'll update my question with my edits,

Comment: @JamesAMohler - The built in converter sucks. I loose all my CSS styling.

Comment: (Edit) @BrianFleishman - I believe you need to specify a full url, not just a relative path, ie `http://servername/yourpage.cfm....` *I don't see that in the documentation* I seem to remember one or two versions did not mention those variables. See https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfexecute.html

Comment: I updated my questions with updated PDF output after changing the path to the full URL.

Comment: (Edit) FWIW, it works fine with URL variables. From the screen shot it like the request is being redirected.  a) What is the actual URL value you are using in the `arguments`? b) Is there any sort of redirection or authentication (that might cause a redirect0 used in your app?

Comment: Yeah I think that's my authentication. Let me work through that part and I'll circle back. I have to move my report page to different directory to eliminate that redirect. Is there anything better to use than this plugin? Cfdocument strips almost all my formatting so I can't use it.

Comment: Well, it should not use lose *all* of your formatting. You can usually make make it work "better" with a little tweaking, but ... for really complex stuff, I agree it is often more effort than it is worth IMO.  That said, realistically, none of the tools I have used are perfect.  They have all had their own "quirks".  It is just the nature of conversion. You have to research and test to determine which one produces the most consistent results for your given requirements.

Comment: I wrote a custom tag that uses WKHTMLTOPDF. We use this on CF8-10 as it is much faster and has better CSS support. https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/74e556e7d4f1a715a41d I recommend always calling a full URL from a webserver and not local files. (NOTE: Here's a demo HTML page to compare results w/CFDocument. https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/b4bb7c29bafef04b3b0d )

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a CF9+ wrapper for WKHTMLTOPDF. It generates the command line arguments and puts them in the correct order. You can also provide separate header, body & footer URLs.

http://gamesover2600.tumblr.com/post/125851537339/generating-pdfs-using-coldfusion-wkhtmltopdf

I recommend saving ColdFusion-generated HTML as a temporary static file to an actual webserver.  This is so that WKHTMLTOPDF doesn't have to deal w/any CF-related session/security obstacles and can correctly determine all related MIME types (something you can't do if you use `file://` parameters.) You can delete the temp files after PDF generation or save them for later review/regeneration.

For page breaks, use CSS `page-break-inside`, `page-break-after` and `page-break-before`.

```
<CF_WKHTMLTOPDF
  AddDefaultHeader = "0"
  PageURL = "http://#CGI.Server_Name#/test_page.htm"
  filename = "c:\test_page.pdf"
  orientation = "portrait"
  DisableSmartShrinking="yes"
  dpi="96"
  PageSize="letter"
  margintop = "0"
  marginleft = "0"
  marginright = "0"
  marginbottom = "0">

<CFDUMP VAR="#WKHMLTOPDF_Result#">
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon the some of the items in the comments:

1. Be sure to test any command line programs *from* the command line first, before plugging it into CFExecute. That allows you to identify any special syntax needed (such as quoting paths containing spaces, etcetera) and identify any potential permissions issues. The latter is not the issue here, but it is a common gotcha with CFExecute, since the CF service tends to run under a lower permission account by default.
2. Always use one of the [available error variables](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfexecute.html). Otherwise, you may not be aware of any errors that occur. (No idea why some recent versions of the CF documentation make no mention those variables...)

   - `errorVariable` - Variable name. Populate this variable name with any error messages
   - `errorFile`     - Absolute File path. Output any text the program writes to `StdErr` to this file. Typically, this translates to mean error messages.

   **NB:** Just be aware that some programs, also write status messages to the StdErr stream, not just errors.  So a non-empty error variable or file does not *always* indicate a problem. WKHTMLToPDF just so happens to be one of those programs, so keep that in mind.
3. Regarding URL variables, those will be evaluated and converted into strings before they ever reach the program. Similar to database queries, the program will only see the *generated* string, after any CF variables have been evaluated.  As long as that argument string is valid for the called program, your code should work fine.
4. Finally, in order for the CFML code contained in that .cfm file to be evaluated by the CF server, you must call it as a URL, ie `http://servername/scriptname.cfm` , and *not* as a local file.  Obviously, verify the target URL is reachable in a browser first.

Putting it all together, this simple test case worked fine under CF11.

**CFExecute**

```
 <cfset url.ticketID = 123>
 <cfset check_signature.id = 456>

 <!--- Note: Arguments containing spaces may need to be enclosed in quotes --->
 <cfexecute name="C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe" 
    arguments="http://localhost:8500/wkhtmlTestPage.cfm?ticket_id=#url.ticketID#&signature_id=#check_signature.id# C:\temp\wkhtmlTest.pdf"
    errorVariable="errorMessage"
    timeout="10"
    /> 

    <cfdump var="#errorMessage#" label="errorVariable">
```

**wkhtmlTestPage.cfm**

```
<cfparam name="URL.ticket_id" default="default ticket_id">
<cfparam name="URL.signature_id" default="default signature_id">

<cfdump var="#URL#">
```

Answer (score 0):

For WKHTMLTOPDF within Coldfusion I am using a .cfc Wrapper (found it [here](https://github.com/LoicMahieu/cf-wkhtmltopdf)). Only thing to change within the .cfc is the path to your WKHTMLTOPDF installation.

And then you can use it like this within your coldfusion file (in this examle with a CF-variable send to the WKHTMLTOPDF options):

```
<cfscript>
   wkhtmltopdf = new Wkhtmltopdf();
   pdf = wkhtmltopdf.fromURL("[path to]/file.html", {'headerRight': '#Application.headertext#'});
</cfscript>
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" variable="#pdf#"></cfcontent>
```